# HTML5/webcomponents: Call prototype function from template code

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm making some tests for using (or not) web components in a single page app I'm creating.

Here's an example for the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<template id="aTemplate">
    <div style="border:1px solid red">
        <p>text <input type="text"></p>
        <button>ClickMe</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    var Proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

    Proto.createdCallback = function () {
        var t = document.querySelector('#aTemplate');
        var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
        this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
    };

    Proto.aFunction = function() {
        alert("proto " + "text value?");
    }

    document.registerElement('x-proto', {prototype: Proto});

    var ProtoChild = Object.create(Proto);

    ProtoChild.createdCallback = function () {
        Proto.createdCallback.call(this)
    };

    ProtoChild.aFunction = function() {
        alert("child " + "text value?");
    }

    document.registerElement('x-proto-child', {
        prototype: Proto
    });

</script>

<x-proto></x-proto>

<x-proto-child></x-proto-child>

</body>
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to set a "onclick" handler in the button (inside the template) that calls the method "aFunction" in the object created using the prototype. The method should be called in the correct object instance, with access to the internal DOM components, and the attributes and functions in the prototype.

I've tried a lot of things, (binding the event after construction, using JS or JQuery, using the created/attached callbacks, a ) but I'm out of ideas.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Thanks to MinusFour for the answer. The line:

> ```
> clone.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.aFunction);
> ```

in what I was trying to do, anyway, resulted in (same but with JQuery, for testing compatibilitiy):

> ```
> $(this.showButton).on("click", this.aFunction.bind(this));
> ```

The "bind" makes 'this' AKA the container, the complete component, available in JS code, what I needed.

Here's the completed final example, someone may find it helpful:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<template id="aTemplate">
    <div style="border:1px solid darkgray;padding:10px;margin: 10px;">
        <h2 class="theCaption"></h2>
        <p>text <input class="theText" type="text"></p>
        <button class="showButton">Show val</button>
        <button class="closeButton">Close</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    // The .bind method from Prototype.js
    if (!Function.prototype.bind) { // check if native implementation available
        Function.prototype.bind = function () {
            var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
                    object = args.shift();
            return function () {
                return fn.apply(object,
                        args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
            };
        };
    }

    function createProto() {
       $("#spawnPoint").append("<x-proto x-caption='proto'></x-proto>");
    }

    function createChild() {
        $("#spawnPoint").append("<x-proto-child x-caption='a child of proto'></x-proto-child>");
    }

    var Proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

    Object.defineProperty(Proto, "x-caption", {value: "no caption"});

    Proto.createdCallback = function () {
        var t = document.querySelector('#aTemplate');
        var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
        this.shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(clone);
        $(clone).children("div").append("<p>ssss</p>")
        this.showButton = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.showButton');
        this.closeButton = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.closeButton');
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.theCaption').textContent = $(this).attr("x-caption");
        this.theText = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.theText');
        $(this.showButton).on("click", this.aFunction.bind(this));
        $(this.closeButton).on("click", this.close.bind(this));
    };

    Proto.aFunction = function () {
        alert("in proto = " + $(this.theText).val());
    }

    Proto.close = function () {
        $(this).detach();
    }

    document.registerElement('x-proto', {prototype: Proto});

    var ProtoChild = Object.create(Proto);

    ProtoChild.createdCallback = function () {
        Proto.createdCallback.call(this);
    };

    ProtoChild.aFunction = function () {
        alert("overrided in child = " + $(this.theText).val());
    }

    document.registerElement('x-proto-child', {
        prototype: ProtoChild
    });

</script>

<button onclick="javascript:createProto()">Create proto</button>
<button onclick="javascript:createChild()">Create child</button>

<div id="spawnPoint">

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could just add the listener from the `importedNode` (`clone` in your case).

```
clone.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  //code logic here
});
```

You also probably meant:

```
document.registerElement('x-proto-child', {
        prototype: ProtoChild
    });
```

Here's how it would look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<template id="aTemplate">
    <div style="border:1px solid red">
        <p>text <input type="text"></p>
        <button>ClickMe</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.7.14/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var Proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
  
    Proto.createdCallback = function () {
        var t = document.querySelector('#aTemplate');
        var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
        clone.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.aFunction);
        this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
    };

    Proto.aFunction = function() {
        alert("proto " + "text value?");
    }

    document.registerElement('x-proto', {prototype: Proto});

    var ProtoChild = Object.create(Proto);

    ProtoChild.createdCallback = function () {
        Proto.createdCallback.call(this);
        console.log(this.template);
        /*this.template.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
          console.log('child');
          });*/
    };

    ProtoChild.aFunction = function() {
        alert("child " + "text value?");
    }

    document.registerElement('x-proto-child', {
        prototype: ProtoChild
    });

</script>

<x-proto></x-proto>

<x-proto-child></x-proto-child>

</body>
```

Comment: This is the answer that pointed me in the right direction, thanks a lot. I'm editing the question for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, a while back:

http://www.davevoyles.com/accessing-member-functions-in-polymer/

Are you using Polymer at all, or just Web Components?

As long as you wrap the functions you are trying to call in the polymer-ready event, you should be good to go, and can call functions from your polymer-element.

> Polymer parses element definitions and handles their upgrade
>   asynchronously. If you prematurely fetch the element from the DOM
>   before it has a chance to upgrade, you’ll be working with a plain
>   HTMLElement, instead of your custom element.

Alternatively, you can query for a custom element however you want (via ID, class, attr, or element name) and get the same thing. Here’s his example: http://jsbin.com/qikaya/2/edit

Comment: I tried to use Polymer, and while my opinion is based in a few lines of test code, and no one should take it seriously, I found it inmature and far from optimal. Anyway I'ts an awesome piece of code, with really great ideas, that shows the future in web-dev.